# multer: can do [req.file.filename] but need [req.files[0].filename] or [req.files.find({fieldname:"samplefield"})]

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, multer

After uploading my files using `multer_upload.single('sample_fieldname')` , I can retrieve the data using `req.file.*`. But how do I do retrieve this same data when I use multer with multiple files? Such as: `multer_upload.fields([{...}])` or `multer_upload.any(...)`?

I've tried things such as `req.files[0]` and `req.files.find({fieldname:"sample_fieldname"})` but, since multer is just a middleware, these don't actually do anything.

How would I retrieve this data?

Answer (score 0):

see: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html

```
router.post(
'/', 
upload.fields([
   {name:"file_1"},
   {name:"file_2"}
]), (req, res, next) => {
   console.log(req.files['file_2'][0]); // this line prints the info for that file
}
```